# Not getting any error or success message while integrating NAB payment gateway

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I have tried so far:

```
<?php
    $url = "https://demo.transact.nab.com.au/xmlapi/payment";
        $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "XML=".$xml);
            $content=curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
           print_r('<pre>');
            print_r($content);
            print_r('</pre>');


            $array_data = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($content)), true);



            print_r('<pre>');
            print_r($array_data);
            print_r('</pre>');

            ?>
```

I am not getting any success or error message while trying the same code. Not getting any message in JSON or array format.
It's a NAB Transact payment gateway.

Comment: What are you sending by `$xml`? - Anything you're sending now is returning an invalid request (errorcode 515)

Comment: Yes i am getting the same. how to solve this

Comment: I have added and updated my answer below. Please check.

Comment: Did my answer help you? Please mark as solved if it did, for other users experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

*I have to write this as an answer, because of the code examples.*

Did you look in the NabTransact Integration Guide, or anything that has been sent to you before you've started this issue? Error 515 means there is a "*fatal error due to unknown reasons*". Once I've had a similar error, my headers were not right.

You could try to use use `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` since it is not defined:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                   'Content-type: application/xml', 
                                   'Content-length: ' . strlen($xml)
                                 ));
```

And making sure `$xml` is all in one-line.

.

**What does the Integration Guide say?**

The Integration Guide says the following:

> Chapter 8. XML Over HTTP
>
> *The structure of the HTTP request and response messages will need to conform to the HTTP 1.1 network protocol. (...) **Important: The HTTP
>   communication between the client als NAB Transact Payment Gateway must
>   be done via SSL socket so that sensitive information included in the
>   request and response messages are encrypted.***
>
> 8.1 Request
>
> ```
> POST /test/payment HTTP/1.1
> host: www.NABTransact.com.au
> content-type: text/xml
> content-length: 677
>
> <?xml-rubbish here, all in one-line>
> ```
>
> .
>
> 8.2 Response
>
> *The initial HTTP server response (100 continue) is to indicate that the request has been received and should be ignored. The 200 response should follow with the XML response message. If content length is 0 and no XML response is included then the request could not be understood and no response was produced.*

Followed by a XML-response with data.

So, make sure you're using the correct headers in your cURL **and** using SSL. If you cannot use an official SSL certificate because you're working on localhost, there are tricks in cURL where you can use your own certificate or bypassing the SSL-check.